# Parsing XML escape sequences with MATLAB's xmlread()

Tags: xml, matlab, escaping

MATLAB's (v2103a) xmlread() function fails when it encounters international escape sequences such as `&ntilde;`. Does anyone have a clean work around?

For example when parsing an XML file with the following XML snippet:

```
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Perdidas - A&ntilde;o0 (euros)</Data></Cell>
```

xmlread() fails with the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] resultados.xml:236:50: The entity "ntilde" was referenced, but not declared.
```

Comment: The entity `&ntilde;` is [not valid XML by default](http://www.slickdev.com/2010/02/13/special_character_encoding_in_xml/). Does your XML file have a DTD and/or can you add one manually or do you need to do something programmatically.

Comment: There are some useful [lists of entities here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html), particularly the "HTMLlat1.ent" file.

Comment: @horchler the XML document does not have a DOCTYPE DTD and I am trying to process it programatically. It could be possible to have my script add a DOCTYPE entry at the top, save the text file and then run xmlread(). If that seems workable, could you write up a full description as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's tools for dealing with DTDs are incomplete. Notably, if you read in an XML file using `xmlread` with an included DTD, and then use `xmlwrite` to save it back out, all of the DTD content will be stripped out (entity substitutions are performed, so you can still parse and read in the new file without errors). There's no simple *and* truly robust way of just inserting a DTD – this XML where everything is strict and one ought to be very careful when reading and writing from the files.

However, using some old code, I've hacked together a non-robust solution that may work in simple cases as long as you check the output. You can download the M-file and an example XML file [here](http://biorobots.cwru.edu/personnel/adh/stackoverflow/06/). The `xmlentity` function adds DTD entities to an XML file by reading in the contents, performing some crude parsing, and writing out the new data.

I used the following `'example.xml'` XML file ([from here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/11/01/xml-and-matlab-navigating-a-tree/)), edited to include some HTML entities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddressBook>
   <Entry>
      <Name>Frie&ntilde;dly J.&nbsp;Mathworker</Name>
      <PhoneNumber>(508) 647-7000</PhoneNumber>
      <Address hasZip="no" type="work">3 Apple Hill Dr, Natick MA</Address>
   </Entry>
</AddressBook>
```

Calling `xmlread('example.html')` on this file returns an error like the one you're seeing because it's not valid XML. To fix this, the two entities that are used (lists of others can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html)) are defined and my `xmlentity` function is called:

```
entities = {'nbsp','&#160;';
            'ntilde','&#241;'};
domNode = xmlentity(entities,'example.xml','example2.xml')
```

This produces the following XML file in `'example2.xml'`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE AddressBook
[
   <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
   <!ENTITY ntilde "&#241;">
]>
<AddressBook>
   <Entry>
      <Name>Frie&ntilde;dly J.&nbsp;Mathworker</Name>
      <PhoneNumber>(508) 647-7000</PhoneNumber>
      <Address hasZip="no" type="work">3 Apple Hill Dr, Natick MA</Address>
   </Entry>
</AddressBook>
```

Additionally

```
domNode.getElementsByTagName('Name').item(0).getTextContent
```

returns `'Frieñdly J. Mathworker'`. See the help in `xmlentity` for further details and caveats.

There are many other ways to deal with this and my code could probably be adapted to use some of them. External DTDs are convenient as they allow you to use one file to declare all of your entities and then you just need to indicate the URI of this file in a simple DTD (and set the XML file to not be standalone). XSLT/Schema is another option. It's much more complicated, but has many more features. Matlab has better support for it too, but it still takes work.